# C# Calculate points on SVG path

Tags: c#, vector, polygon, svg

What should I do to get a list of points from an SVG path. I know in terms of web development you simply use the SVG library to determine the length of a path and then just sample it at given intervals. The only issue that I cannot seem to find and equivalent library and or methods for doing this in plain C#.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you not including the DOT NET Framework (and its Graphics libraries) as part-and-parcel of plain C#?

Comment: O course I am including .net I am just saying this is not asp.net or something

Comment: SVG is simply done in XML. You could just read the xml tags and parse them. The specs are easily found : http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html